# Regular Expression; Finding a word(s) between 2 specific words in a single string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

```
Account has been reset and assigned the following temporary password:

NvSYVZeg

Please log into your account using your email address and the temporary password.
```

What I want to do is grab the  temporary password (the **NvSYVZeg** part) and put it into it's own string variable.  I've looked for hours and tried multiple expressions that I've found online (tested them at RegexStorm.com & RegExr.com) and they never seem to locate the temp password.  I tried:

```
(?<=password:\s)(.*?)(?=\sPlease)
```

and

```
(password:)(.*?)(Please)
```

But neither of them worked for me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than 1 whitespace in between the password and leading/trailing delimiters. Thus, you need to use `\s*` (any 0 *or more* whitespace symbols):

```
password:\s*(.*?)\s*Please
         ^^^     ^^^
```

or

```
(?<=password:\s*).*?(?=\s*Please)
             ^^^       ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3Dpassword%3A%5Cs*%29.*%3F%28%3F%3D%5Cs*Please%29&i=Account%20has%20been%20reset%20and%20assigned%20the%20following%20temporary%20password%3A%0D%0A%0D%0ANvSYVZeg%0D%0A%0D%0APlease%20log%20into%20your%20account%20using%20your%20email%20address%20and%20the%20temporary%20password.).

The first one might be used like

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"password:\s*(.*?)\s*Please");
if (m.Success) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

If you use the second one, just access `m.Value`.

Comment: This is what worked for me, thank you!  And for anyone that needs the clarification, the 's' in the 3rd code block needs to be your string that you want to run the Regex against.  The var m also comes back with curly brackets, but I just used the Replace() method get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

By using the regex option of `RightToLeft` we tell the parser to work backwards instead of forwards which in my mind makes it easier to craft a pattern. *Note that though the parser works in reverse our pattern is still represented as a forward manner as usual*.

---

If we mentally, in our pattern, work backwards from an anchor `^Password` we just have to eat all spaces by specifying `\s+`. Then all we have to do once all spaces are consumed is to extract all until a newline. The pattern would be

```
 (?<Password>[^\r\n]+)\s+^Please
```

Then extract the actual password in C# by using the named group `myMatch.Groups["Password"].value`.

Note with the `^` in the pattern we will also need the option `Multiline` as well.